# how to "filter" peaks in dataset with experimental errors (Python)

Tags: python, plot

I have some datsets which plot curves similar to a gaussian curve, with a large peak at the center, and two almost flat parts at the sides. The problem is that some of these datasets contain experimental errors, which result in step-like formations at the sides, and this is a problem because I have to calculate the incremental ratio at each step in the dataset to find the max slope, and those steps give me a super high derivative, which in some cases are higher than the right peak.

Here is one of the problematic plots:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwyip.png)

The blue line is the dataset, the red one the derivative, and the green dots are the peaks (for now just calculated as max(derivative) and min(derivative).

How can I filter out those peaks? I heard something about renormalization and that it could help with this, but I don't know what that is (I'm just a student and I'm doing this for my mom :) so I don't know what that means)

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is large enough, a simple median filter should do the job. Consider your dataset point ordered by the x value, and replace each value in the dataset with the median value of N consecutive point. If the errors are usually single points, even a filter with N=3 will work.

[Median filter (Wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter)

Comment: I just looked into the algorithm for this median filter, but would this afffect the dataset in bad ways? for example, the dataset value at the point of the derivative peak would be exactely the same or would it change? (I guess I could keep the true values and then look them up after finding the "modified" peak, but still, just for curiosity)

Comment: just tested it, and it seems like those peaks are gone, and that's good, but the actual peaks of the derivative are now shifted a little bit, and the shift is not really consistent: on average they are 1 unit on the x axis before the right one, but it's not always like that (i see this looking at the datasets without this experimental error, bc the other ones without filter do not show the right peak).

Comment: maybe another option would be to remove the step-like formations from the original dataset and make them flat (possibly bringing them up to the root of the rising edges. Though, again, I don't know how to do it :)